# Deleting the bottom row of TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Thanks a lot for ***DonMag***'s contribution for this question.

#### Original Problem

I implement the swipe to delete row gesture in my code like this:

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            // Delete Rows Action.
            Results.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .fade)
        }
    }
```

and here is a picture of how it looks like.

[image: Glitch]

what I want to achieve:

[image: Phone Records animation]

Platform: Xcode 10, iOS 12.

#### Solution

***DonMag*** point out that it is likely be a bug of iOS 12. So the solution next is only a solution for several specific version of iOS. My cells height is 100 so I just input 100 for simplicity. On iOS 13 Apple has fixed the problem.

#### iOS 12

```swift
    // DELETE Action
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        if (editingStyle == .delete && indexPath.row < Results.count) {
            // HIDE the glitch when deleting rows.
            let totalheight = self.tableView.frame.size.height // Total height of screen.
            let contentOffsetY = self.tableView.contentOffset.y // The current position of top
            let SizeShrinkage = (self.tableView.contentSize.height-100 < self.tableView.frame.size.height-getToolbarHeight()-getTitleBarHeight()) && (self.tableView.contentSize.height > self.tableView.frame.size.height-getToolbarHeight()-getTitleBarHeight()) // If the height of content size is near to the screen height.
            let currentHeight = contentOffsetY + totalheight - getToolbarHeight() // Current position of bottom. (with toolbar.)
            let contentHeight = self.tableView.contentSize.height
            MovingOffset = Double(currentHeight - contentHeight + 100) // The distance from the content's bottom edge to the top of toolbar (The length that the content exceeded from the safe area) after deleting a row.
            let onlyOnBottom = (MovingOffset <= 100 && MovingOffset > 0) // It's on the bottom. The exceeded is larger than 0.
            // Delete Rows Action.
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            if (onlyOnBottom || SizeShrinkage) {
                tableView.contentInset.bottom += (currentHeight-contentHeight+100) // Set the inset that it exceeded
            }
            Results.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            tableView.endUpdates()
            
            if SizeShrinkage {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NotificationDeleteOversizedRecordKey), object: self)
            } else if onlyOnBottom {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NotificationDeleteBottomRecordKey), object: self)
            }
        }
    }
```

`getToolbarHeight()` and `getTitleBarHeight()`are my customize function that could get toolbar height and titlebar height for different device. And I add two listener in NFCenter and let them handle the rest animation. It is because I found that when I run animation in the deleting row function, sometimes the animation will not execute.

```swift
     /**
     Delete Animation
     */
    @objc func scrollOneLineUp(_ button: UIBarButtonItem?) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 8.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {self.tableView.contentInset.bottom=0}, completion: {finished in self.tableView.contentOffset.y += CGFloat(self.MovingOffset)})
    }
    @objc func scrollToTop(_ button: UIBarButtonItem?) {
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.5) {
            self.tableView.contentInset.bottom = 0
        }
    }
```

and here is what it finally looks like. When deleting "Water 5" and "Water 6", to hide the glitch, it will moves to the top (just to the top, but not showing the large title, it was me dragging down that let it show large title), and other time it will move 1 row.
for the rows that less than water 5, we don't need to handle glitch. It looks quite great.

[image: What it finally looks like]

#### iOS 11

On iOS 11, the animation looks nice in most of the time. However, when deleting a certain row, that after deleting it the content size is firstly smaller than the content revealing area, there will be a glitch. The solution for iOS 11 is much simpler than iOS 12.

implement this in the deleting row function (`override func tableView`)

```swift
if(tableView.contentSize.height<=tableView.bounds.height+100.0 && tableView.contentSize.height>tableView.bounds.height) {
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
}
// The 100.0f is the cell height.
```

The 100.0f is the cell's height. So when the content's height firstly smaller than the tableView's border, the tableview scrolls to the very top, and the glitch animation is covered by the scrolling animation.

Other version of iOS does not have large title, and the height of toolbar, title bar and status bar's height is always changing so I did not test them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 2**

After some experimentation, it appears to be an issue with `iOS 12` (at least, on my `iOS 12.4` simulator *and* device).

This can be (somewhat) confirmed by

- launch the default iPhone **Reminders** app
- add a bunch of reminders (I just used A, B, C, etc...) so you have enough that scrolling is needed
- scroll down to the last row
- delete the last row

You'll see that the row deletion animation is faulty. In fact, deleting any row does not provide the smooth animation we see in `iOS 13`.

Doing some searching I find similar issues back with `iOS 7` reportedly fixed in `iOS 8+` ... so perhaps the same bug returned in one of the `iOS 12` versions. You *may* be able to use one of those older work-arounds, but based on comments it was pretty hit-or-miss.

I still stand by my initial comment, though, that there is no reason for:

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .fade)
```

to be called after the row deletion.

---

**Original Answer**

It sounds like you are doing too much...

This is all you should need to get the row to delete and the other rows to "slide down":

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        Results.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

No need to reload the data.

See example here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a40Uy.jpg

---

**Edit**

Here is a complete (very simple) example. No `@IBOutlet` or `@IBAction` connections... just add a new table view controller to your Storyboard and assign its custom class to `SampleTableViewController`:

```
class SampleCell: UITableViewCell {

    let testView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .blue
        return v
    }()
    let testLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .cyan
        return v
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    @objc
    func commonInit() -> Void {

        contentView.addSubview(testView)
        contentView.addSubview(testLabel)
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide

        // avoid constraint warnings
        let c = testView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        c.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            c,
            testView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            testView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),
            testView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.heightAnchor),

            testLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.trailingAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            testLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.centerYAnchor),
            testLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

        ])

    }

}

class SampleTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var data: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // fill data array with 30 strings
        data = (1...30).map { "This is row \($0)" }

        tableView.register(SampleCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SampleCell")
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SampleCell", for: indexPath) as! SampleCell
        c.testLabel.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return c
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            data.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems does not work... What I mean is that, when I have already scroll to the bottom of the tableView (the tableView's content is longer than the screen), if I delete a row, the whole table will suddenly move 1 cell down without any animation. However, if we check Apple's app like mail or message, when we are at the bottom of the tableView, when deleting a row, the table will gently move 1 cell down, not only have the cells fade animation, but also the whole table's moving animation.

Comment: Oh... so are you building your project with Xcode 11?

Comment: @user13126278 - Xcode 10 or 11 shouldn't matter. I edited my answer with a complete example for you to try.

Comment: Ok... But when I test it on my Xcode10.1, after compiling this it will glitch. Maybe it's a bug for certain version of Xcode. But anyway, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @user13126278 - after testing, it does appear to be an `iOS 12` bug... see my **Edit 2** at the top of my answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I have delete the extra code in my project. Thank you so much!